# Sign app in xcode with ios5

Tags: iphone, ios5

I face a problem while I sign the app with ios sdk5, this problem I have never faced before ...

error message as follows:

```
iPhone Distribution: iApp: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: AppDever" 
in /Library/Keychains/System.keychain and "iPhone Distribution: AppDever" in 
/Users/icoco/Library/Keychains/login.keychain)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I often import the certificate file into 'login' and 'system' , but now it seem report error ...

anyone can give help ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you imported the certificate into the system keychain and your user one. I'd try removing it from one of them.

Comment: hi, yes... I import the certificate to both before, 'login' and 'system' , it works on old ios sdk but sdk 5 now...

Comment: Try removing one of them, it seems to get confused pretty easily. I usually keep mine in my user keychain, not the system one.